# display block ignores media query change when screen size changes?

Tags: javascript, css

trying to create a responsive menu. So far it works in small screens but when increase the size screen the menu does not come back to the media query setting for big screens and it just shows the toggled class from the javascript.

So if the menu is toggled on and i increase the screen it does not fix the menu style and the same happens if it is toggled off and the screen increases

```js
const burgerArray = document.querySelectorAll(".barra");
const navBar = document.getElementById('myLinks')

function buttonChange() {
  for (i = 0; i < burgerArray.length; i++) {

    burgerArray[i].classList.toggle('change')
    console.log(burgerArray[i])
  }
  if (navBar.style.display == "block") { // if is menuBox displayed, hide it
    navBar.style.display = "none";
  } else { // if is menuBox hidden, display it
    navBar.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
@media (max-width: 468px) {
  .myLinks {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .menudo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  #burgers {
    display: none;
  }
  .myLinks {
    display: block;
  }
}

;
```

```html
<div class="menudo">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="/index.html" id="logo"><img src="img/PicsArt_02-11-12.55.38 (1).png" width=7 0px alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <label for="checkbox">
            <div onclick="buttonChange()" id='burgers' class="burger-menuu">
                <div class="barra" id="bar1" ></div>
                <div class="barra" id="bar2" ></div>
                <div class="barra" id="bar3" ></div>
            </div>
        </label>
  <nav class="myLinks" id="myLinks">
    <a id="menu-land" href="/artic.html">Articles</a>
    <a id="menu-land" href="img/Francisco Gonzalez Resume.pdf" target="blank">Resume<!--<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true">--></i>
        </nav> 
    </div>
```

Comment: If you using inline styles then make sure your css has `!important` to override but the better approach is to add/remove a class for the display block/none instead, so it will be much easier to control everything from css. You could also set the display to "" to remove the inline styles on resize in js

Comment: Still not working. Tried to do it in a new environment and it all works. only problem is that it does not apply the styles when it is resized.

Comment: i don't know what you tried or if you understood what my comment at all

Answer (score 0):

There is some gap between your media queries. Try to set your `min-width: 469px` to apply other styles while resizing viewport

```css
@media (max-width: 468px) {
  .myLinks {
      display: block;
      background-color: bisque;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 469px) {

.menudo {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
#burgers {
   display: none;
}
   .myLinks {
       display: block;
       background-color: lightgreen;
   }
};
```

```html
<div class="menudo">
    <div class="logo"><a href="/index.html" id="logo"><img src="img/PicsArt_02-11-12.55.38 (1).png" width= 70px
            alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <label for="checkbox">
            <div onclick="buttonChange()" id='burgers' class="burger-menuu">
                <div class="barra" id="bar1" ></div>
                <div class="barra" id="bar2" ></div>
                <div class="barra" id="bar3" ></div>
            </div>
        </label>
        <nav class="myLinks" id="myLinks">
            <a id="menu-land" href="/artic.html">Articles</a>
            <a id="menu-land" href="img/Francisco Gonzalez Resume.pdf" target="blank">Resume<!--<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true">--></i>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Just trying to make it work first. It does toggle the menu but when I resize the screen it keeps the javascript display instead of reacting to the media query

Comment: @FranciscoAzocar The media query css will NOT replace your inline css set by javascript

Comment: I tried adding an !important and still not working. I would like to try this ".You could also set the display to remove the inline styles on resize in js" but dont know how to do that. Can you elaborate a bit please?

Answer (score 0):

As document.getElementById('table').styles.* is styling the element inline through the DOM which has a higher priority than the media queries do through CSS. Nothing will happen because the DOM elements now have a higher priority styling, so the MQ rules are ignored.

So to create a higher priority for the media query I used !important as @Huangism suggested and changed this block of code:

```
.myLinks {
   display: block;
   background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

for This block:

```
#myLinks {
   display: block !important;
}
```